# WebView renders in the wrong location in my ScreenSaverView

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit

I've written a screen saver that displays a web page.  It works exactly as I want it to on my main display, but in the preview and secondary displays, the web view is hanging off the top of the screen.

Example (from preview):

[screen saver bug http://img.skitch.com/20081212-nk5cqrgfds1funr1a3p72aw25q.preview.jpg](http://skitch.com/dlsspy/6mds/screen-saver-bug)
Uploaded with [plasq](http://plasq.com/)'s [Skitch](http://skitch.com)!

My code is pretty straightforward.  From within `initWithFrame:isPreview:` I have the following code:

```
webview = [[WebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame
                           frameName:@"main"
                           groupName:@"main"];
[self addSubview:webview];
```

Does anyone have any idea what's happening?

If anyone wants to play with the project, [the code](http://github.com/dustin/websaver) is on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your code and you're using the superview's (WebSaverView) frame rectangle as the WebView's frame. You should instead use it's bounding rectangle (`[self bounds]`). The bounding rectangle represents the area "inside" the superview. As you've seen, the two may not always have the same origin, which is causing this issue. You should not be adjusting the frame you're passed in `initWithFrame:`, since the origin probably has a very good reason for not being 0,0.

Comment: I'm curious about what this reason might be.  On my primary display, it's 1440x900 at 0,0, but on my secondary, it's 1920x1200 at 1440,452.  What value do these provide?  Thanks for the insight, this does solve my problem and feel less ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the frame you're giving the WebView is in the wrong coordinates. Remember that a view's frame is expressed in terms of the superview's coordinate system (bounds).

You should be making the view as big as the superview's `-bounds`, if I get correctly what you want to do: usually a rect from (0,0) to (width,height).

Comment: Interesting.  I did a bit more inspection around the frame that was coming in and found that the origin offset was just...weird.  If I set it to 0, the right thing happens.